# jackson ignore default value when it's true

Tags: java, jackson

I'm having a class that has a default value which is `true` and I want to ignore the default in serialization. It works when the default is `false`, but not when the default is `true`:

```java
    public static final class TestBooleanDefaultTrue {
        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
        @JsonProperty(value="display")
        public Boolean display = Boolean.TRUE;
        public String s = "test";

        public TestBooleanDefaultTrue() {}
    }

    public static final class TestBooleanDefaultFalse {
        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
        @JsonProperty(value="display")
        public Boolean display = Boolean.FALSE;
        public String s = "test";

        public TestBooleanDefaultFalse() {}
    }

    @Test
    public void readBVMTest() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        testom.writeValue(System.out, new TestBooleanDefaultTrue());
        testom.writeValue(System.out, new TestBooleanDefaultFalse());
    }
```

which outputs (after cheating a bit):

```
{"s":"test","display":true}
{"s":"test"}
```

How can I ignore the default value when it is `true`?

Comment: You could look into `JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM` and specify a filter class via `valueFilter`, s.t. it filters when the value is `Boolean.TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom filter, because the `NON_DEFAULT` does not consider what you assign, but the default value of the wrapper type.

```
 public static final class MyFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Boolean)) {
            return false;
        }
        // date should be in the past
        final Boolean v = (Boolean) obj;
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(v);
    }
}

public static final class TestBooleanDefaultTrue {

    @JsonInclude(value = Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = MyFilter.class)
    @JsonProperty(value = "display")
    public Boolean display = Boolean.TRUE;
    public String s = "test";

    public TestBooleanDefaultTrue() {
    }
}



public static final class TestBooleanDefaultFalse {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    @JsonProperty(value = "display")
    public Boolean display = Boolean.FALSE;
    public String s = "test";

    public TestBooleanDefaultFalse() {
    }
}

@Test
public void readBVMTest() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    assertEquals(getOM().writeValueAsString(new TestBooleanDefaultTrue()), "{\"s\":\"test\"}");
    assertEquals(getOM().writeValueAsString(new TestBooleanDefaultFalse()), "{\"s\":\"test\"}");

}
```

EDIT for completeness from the javadoc of `JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT`, emphasis mine:

> When NOT used for a POJO (that is, as a global default, or as *property override*), definition is such that:
>   All values considered "empty" (as per NON_EMPTY) are excluded,
>   *Primitive/wrapper default values are excluded*,
>   Date/time values that have timestamp (`long` value of milliseconds since epoch, see Date) of `0L` are excluded

Comment: Ok, I think I understand... If I look at [the doc for NONDEFAULT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT), I read 

> When used for a POJO ...

and I thought I was in that case, but I realize that I'm at property level and not at POJO level. Ok thanks!